# Access "class session" from another class

Tags: c#, class, global-variables

First: Excuse me if the question is wrong, I don't really know how to describe it since I'm not a pro on coding terms.

So I have written this line in the main class:

```
    public Log log = new Log("program.log");
```

Which starts a session of my logger. I then use that session to write to the log everywhere in my main class code.
But I am doing the dirty work in another class, so I want to log there too. How do I access the same "log session" from that class?

Writing MainClassName.log doesn't work.

Comment: Could you pass `log` as argument to your other class' methods? `obj.doSomething(ref log, [other args]);` (too scarred to post an answer under jonskeet <_<)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `MainClassName.log` won't work because your variable is an *instance* variable. It would need to be a *static* variable... or you'd have to have an instance of `MainClassName` through which to access the instance variable.

However, personally I'd advise you not to use public variables at all. I would suggest using private variables for everything other than "constants" (where that can be a readonly variable of an immutable type, not just something that .NET considers a constant) - and even then in many cases.

I would also suggest the use of something like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) - and you're likely to benefit from using a separate logging object per class, so that you can easily switch logs from different classes on or off (or use even more fine-grained control with severities).

Comment: Creating an instance of the main class is the easiest solution for now, thank you for reminding me of it!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control the logger yourself, you could implement it as a singleton, so you always get the same instance from everywhere in your app domain: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

I'm surprised Jon Skeet advices using log4net when Trace has gotten such a nice upgrade to TraceSource. Allows you to control different output mechanisms, filters, sources and verbosity in your app.config/web.config.